# Should I worry about File handles in logging from async methods?

Tags: node.js, file-io, asynchronous

I'm using the [`each()` method of the async lib](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) and experiencing some very odd (and inconsistent) errors that appear to be File handle errors when I attempt to log to file from within the child processes.

The array that I'm handing to this method frequently has hundreds of items and I'm curious if Node is having trouble running out of available file handles as it tries to log to file from within all these simultaneous processes.  The problem goes away when I comment out my log calls, so it's definitely related to this somehow, but I'm having a tough time tracking down why.

All the logging is trying to go into a single file... I'm entirely unclear on how that works given that each write (presumably) blocks, which makes me wonder how all these simultaneous processes are able to run independently if they're all sitting around waiting on the file to become available to write to.

Assuming that this IS the source of my troubles, what's the right way to log from a process such as `Asnyc.each()` which runs N number of processes at once?

Comment: Show us your code that is relevant to the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, there's a lot of code... you're curious to see the specifics of how I write to file?

Comment: How much code could possibly be involved in the logging process?  Show the general skeleton of the async calls, and the call to the logging method.  Tell us what logging framework you're using, or show us the code in the logging method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, you're correct, I just wanted to know specifically what you wanted to see.  It'll take me a bit to pull the relevant lines together into useful chunks. I'll do it when I get home in a couple of hours.

Comment: Posting the specific errors would be really helpful. It's a lot easier for us to answer concretely than to write a generic treatise on highly-scalable IO in node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have some adjustable limit to how many concurrent/outstanding `write` calls you are going to do. No, none of them will block, but I think `async.eachLimit` or `async.queue` will give you the flexibility to set the limit low and be sure things behave and then gradually increase it to find out what resource constraints you eventually bump up against.

Comment: No no... the async.each() process is calling the same logging method over and over (frequently at the exact same moment) but the file is all one log file.